# Cocoa NSTextView changing word size

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSTextView object on my window. I pass NSStrings into it and it displays. I would like to change the size of the words displayed. How do I do that? Do I do it in the inspector or is there a way to do that in code? Please give an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTextField` is derived from `NSControl` which exposes a `font` property ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setFont%3a)):

```
textField.font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Something" size:12.0];
```